# Create [NS]Dictionary from single string in Swift

Tags: string, dictionary, swift, casting, nsdictionary

I have a string `var dictAsString:String = '["foo" : 123, "bar" : 456]'` that I want to convert to a `Dictionary` (or `NSDictionary`, I'm not particular.) I've tried

```
var dictAsObj:AnyObject = dictAsString as AnyObject
var dictAsDict:NSDictionary = dictAsObj as NSDictionary
```

but that doesn't work. I've also tried

```
var dictAsDict:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(objectsAndKeys: dictAsString)
```

and

```
var dictAsObj:AnyObject = dictAsString as AnyObject
var dictAsDict:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(objectsAndKeys: dictAsObj)
```

Nothing seems to work, and I can't seem to find any help in the documentation. Any ideas?

Comment: where do you get this string form?

Comment: @BryanChen from an api, why?

Comment: if you can change the format to JSON, it will be much easier to parse.

Answer (score 0):

That string resembles a JSON object.

You could replace the square brackets with curly brackets and use **NSJSONSerialization** class to get a dictionary out of it.

Worst case scenario, you should write a little parser.

I suggest using **Ragel**.

Both tasks are an overkill for a string like that, though.